# PowerShell try/catch/finally not working for New-EventLog

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I seem to be having an issue with try catch finally in one of my PowerShell scripts. I cant seem to catch the `System.InvalidOperationException` error in my block. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
try {
    New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "Update Service";
} catch [System.InvalidOperationException] {
    Write-Host "Error";
    Write-Host $Error[0].Exception;
} finally {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue";
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I get the error when the New-EventLog source already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't catch that exception because it's not an `InvalidOperationException` in the first place.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
    New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'Update Service'
} catch {
    $_.Exception.GetType().FullName   # Output: System.Exception
} finally{
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
}
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, Thank you of your help. This works much better.